# How to show that the dot product of $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ can be expressed as $h(x)^{tr} * h(y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, determinant, isometry

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 175, it is given that

> Let $h(x) = A \cdot x$, where $A$ is orthogonal n-by-n matrix; we show
>   $h$ is an isometry by showing that is preserves the dot product.Now
>   the dot product of $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ can be expressed as
>
> $$h(x)^{tr} * h(y)$$ [...]

But I do not understand how can 
$$h(x) \cdot h(y) = h(x)^{tr} * h(y)$$ ?

Comment: Expand the expressions in both members (possibly with a numerical example) and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, $n=4$.  If you have two $4 \times 1$ matrices,
$$
\mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\mathbf{v}= \begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the transpose of $\mathbf{u}$ is a $1 \times 4$ matrix
$$
\mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{tr}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\quad a_2\quad a_3\quad a_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
When you multiply matrices, you get a $1 \times 1$ matrix
$$
\mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{tr}}\;\mathbf{v} =
\left[a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + a_4b_4\right]
$$
Then, by convention, we consider a $1 \times 1$ matrix to be the same thing as a scalar, so we have the dot product $\mathbf{u}\,\cdot\,\mathbf{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

$h(x),\,h(y)$ are represented by $n\times 1$ matrices, so $\;{}^{\mathrm t}h(x)\cdot h(x)\;$ is the product of a $1\times n$ matrix by an $n\times 1$ matrix, i.e. a number.